# slide transitions in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am trying to achieve slide transitions similar to JQueryMobile using AngularJS routing.

JQuery Mobile here: http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/transitions/

I can try creating a directive that will leverage this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13661642/524511 but wanted to ask if there is something ready-made first.

Comment: Take a look at http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-mobile-nav . It may help...

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely a step in the right direction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update (May 21, 2013)

Animation support was brought to the core Angular.JS library starting version 1.1.4 (currently at stable, at the time of this update).

This is the official announcement of the release. It also embed a Youtube video demonstrating the feature:

http://blog.angularjs.org/2013/04/angularjs-106-universal-irreversibility.html

.

### Original Answer

You may try the Angular-UI stuff.

Two main components can help here:

- Animate, which should do what you want directly
  http://angular-ui.github.io/#/directives-animate
- jQuery path-through (although this may be very tricky to put together)
  http://angular-ui.github.io/#directives-jq

**Note:**
If the links don't work for you, try choosing them from the "Directives" menu. They didn't seem working for me when I wrote this answer. Funny that routing doesn't work as expected in one of Angular's own sites!

Comment: In the few months since I posted this question, they have added a feature directly to the core angularJS library that handles this.  I'm not sure if this is the same as the first link in this answer -- but it's part of core AngularJS now, not part of Angular-UI.
[link to docs](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.directive:ngAnimate)

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

https://github.com/sthomp/angular-slidenav.js

http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##asides

I used the first one. Its very simple and doesn't need an extra library to get the slide transitions.